# How to avoid overflow of Bootstrap thumbnail image?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, xhtml

I am using **bootstrap 2.3.2**

I added a thumbnail with lightbox addon. However, thumbnails overflow from the frame and it looks weird.
[image]
When I delete the class 'thumbnail' looks okay. But at this time, the lightbox doesn't work.

My code is

```
<ul class="thumbnails" data-toggle="lightbox">
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/1/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/1/" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/2/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/2/" alt="">
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/3/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/3/" alt="">
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/4/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/4/" alt="">
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/1/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/1/" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/2/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/2/" alt="">
       </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/3/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/3/" alt="">
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/4/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/4/" alt="">
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/1/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/1/" alt="">
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/2/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/2/" alt="">
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/3/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/3/" alt="">
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="span3"> 
        <a href="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/transport/4/" 
           title="Image #1" data-description="Lorem ipsum dolor" 
           class="thumbnail">
           <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/transport/4/" alt="">
        </a>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can do something like .thumbnail img{width:190px} in your custom_ss.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been playing around with your site in IE11 using their developer tools and I believe I have found the answer to your problem. on .main_content img in your CSS styles padding is set to 0px. Since I am not using the actual CSS file to debug this might be cause by inheriting a style from another element. Either way if you set your images to have a padding of 0 you should be in better shape. I did notice that there does still appear to be a slight different in your left and right margin.

```
.main_content img {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Hopefully this gets you in a better place to format your thumbnail gallery.

-Cheers